# Linux command for physical memory, getting the value only

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal` gets back `MemTotal:     12298824 kB`

I want only the numbers here

so i wrote `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | cut -d':' -f2` which gave me `12298824 kB`

I only want the numbers here, can anyone help me?

Note: `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d'k' -f1` gives me the solution `12298824`, but is there a better way? one liner?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **awk**:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

From [@Lars Wirzenius's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25148/lars-wirzenius) comment(No `cat` and No `grep`):

```
awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: Thanks that is really nice.. can you explain what is awk doing here?

Comment: `awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo` avoids `cat` and `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

I have used:

```
dmidecode -t 17 | grep Size | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'
```

to great effect in my CentOS kickstart %pre section.  It returns the total installed amount of memory in MB.  Even if you have empty memory banks, awk will ignore them and only add the integer results.

Comment: `dmidecode` isn't available on all architectures, so use it with caution. In particular, it's not available on ppc/ppc64, and s390/s390x.