# value of total physical memory in linux OS

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have a following question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546241/linux-command-for-physical-memory-getting-the-value-only). **Is the value of the total physical memory always shown in KB?** Because I would like to print it in GB and I use this command

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{$2=$2/(1024^2); print $2}'
```

I'm not sure wheter I should add a if statement to prove the command `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` showing KB value or other value

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the value of the total physical memory always shown in KB?

Yes, the unit `kB` is fixed in the kernel code. See: [1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4634129ad9fdc89d10b597fc6f8f4336fb61e105/fs/proc/meminfo.c#L58) and [2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4634129ad9fdc89d10b597fc6f8f4336fb61e105/fs/proc/meminfo.c#L29)

Comment: They make a 10 bits shift, so to be precise, it's in KiB

Answer (score 4):

You need not to use `grep` + `awk`, you could do this in a single `awk` itself. From explanation point of view, I have combined your attempted `grep` code within `awk` code itself. In `awk` program I am checking condition if 1st field is `MemTotal:` and 3rd field is `kB` then printing 2rd field's value in GB(taken from OP's attempted code itself).

```
awk '$1=="MemTotal:" && $3=="kB"{print $2/(1024^2)}' /proc/meminfo
```

***OR*** if in case you want to make `kB` match in 3rd a case in-sensitive one then try following code:

```
awk '$1=="MemTotal:" && $3~/^[kK][bB]$/{print $2/(1024^2)}' /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the `MemTotal:` entry is always the first line of `/proc/meminfo`, it is possible to get the Gigabyte value without spawning a sub-shell or external commands, and using only POSIX-shell grammar that works with ksh, ash, dsh, zsh, or bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

IFS=': ' read -r _ memTotal _ < /proc/meminfo;

printf 'Total RAM: %d GB\n' "$((memTotal / 1024000))"
```